# jQuery bind/on load not working in Edge or iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, microsoft-edge

I have a preloader working fine in Chrome, FF and IE11 but I'm having no luck getting it to work in Edge or iOS. It behaves the same in both those browsers - it seems 'bind' isn't working so the preloader isn't removed and the opacity of #lightSlider doesn't change.

I tried 'on' but that didn't help, and none of the solutions to resolve a possible caching issue seemed to help either. It does feel like it must be a caching issue but I'm at a loss how to fix it.

```
if ($('#front-page-hero').length ) {

    var bgUrl = $('.page-header').css('background-image');
    bgUrl = bgUrl.replace('url("','').replace('")','');
    var bgFilename = bgUrl.substring(bgUrl.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    var loading = $('<div class="loader">Loading...</div>');
    $('#custom_html-1').prepend(loading);

    var image = $('<img>').attr('src', bgUrl);

    image.bind('load', function(data){
        setTimeout(function(){  
            loading.remove();
            $('#lightSlider').css({ 'opacity' : '1' },0);
        }, 1000);
    });
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably not the problem, but **always** hook the `load` event **before** setting `src`. It's perfectly fine for the browser to see the image is in cache, fire the load event at the image, see that it has no registered handlers, and not queue any callbacks -- all between the line setting `src` and the line hooking the event. (The callbacks have to wait for the event loop. The browser does not have to wait for it before firing the event.)

Comment: You're right that this didn't resolve the issue but it's really useful to know and to understand why that sequence should be followed. I've only just started playing around with JavaScript so a lot of what I'm doing is trial and error.